# Is this a correct way to reverse a singly linked list?

Tags: java, algorithm, singly-linked-list

This is the code that I came up with to reverse a singly-linked-list in Java and I am wondering whether it is correctly done. I know that it works as far as doing its job and having the run time of O(n), but is this a right way to do it or what can be improved? Also what can I do to avoid a stack-overflow problem when reversing a long linked list (without using an iterative alternative), because when trying to reverse a linked list of size greater than 8300, it causes a stack-overflow exception.

```
private void reverse(Node node) {
    if(node != this.tail) {
        reverse(node.next);
        this.tail.next = new Node(node.item);
        this.tail = this.tail.next;
        this.head = this.head.next;
    } 
}

public void reverse() {
    reverse(this.head);
}
```

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?  And btw a recursive approach fails with stack overflow if the list gets too long.

Comment: @Anarug Sharma, your link is a bit broken (when you click on it), maybe just use the html version: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That solution seems fine, however you do not need to create new `Node` objects with the values from old `Node` objects. You can reverse a singly-linked-list in-place and in `O(n)` time complexity.

```java
public Node reverse(Node head) {
   Node prev = null;
   while(head!= null) {
      Node rem = head.next;
      head.next = prev;
      prev = current;
      current = rem;
   }
   return prev;  // prev is the new head of your linked list
}
```

If you do not want to use an iterative solution (although I'd recommend to do so), you can use recursive solution below:

```java
public Node reverseList(Node node) { // send the head of the list
   if(current == null) return null;

   reverse(current);
   return this.tail;  // now tail is the head and head is the tail
}
    
public Node reverse(Node node) {
    if(node.next == null) {
        this.tail = node;
    } else {
        reverse(node.next).next = node;
        node.next = null;
    }
    return node;
}
```

I don't have enough details about your linked list, but I assume you have `this.head` and `this.tail` fields. This solution works even if `this.tail` is not initialized. Moreover, if it is assigned beforehand, you don't need to iterate through the linked list from beginning.

Comment: Is it a mistake to create new Node objects or is this an accepted approach?

Comment: New objects are always created in heap space and reference to these objects are stored in stack memory. It may become inefficient after some point to occupy unnecessary heap space by creating new ```Node``` objects whereas you can do the whole procedure in-place. That's why I recommended not creating new objects and playing with references.

Comment: Stackoverflow expection is raised when the stack size grows bigger than the limit. That's why I'd recommend iterative solution.